# Name of the calling stored procedure with @@nestlevel = 1

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which is nested in several other stored procedure. Is there a way to tell (inside the internal stored procedure) which is the caller?

```
CREATE PROC int_proc 
AS

SELECT int_name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
      ,ext_name = 'How can I tell which is the ext_proc name?'
      ,nestlevel = @@NESTLEVEL

GO
CREATE PROC ext_proc1
AS
SELECT ext_name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),nestlevel = @@NESTLEVEL
EXECUTE int_proc

GO
CREATE PROC ext_proc2
AS
SELECT ext_name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID),nestlevel = @@NESTLEVEL
EXECUTE int_proc

GO

EXEC ext_proc1
EXEC ext_proc2
```

I'm using SQL-Server 2005

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148004/find-out-the-calling-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: sorry, you are right, I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. The "stack" isn't available to us

Why do you need this? FYI, I pass in @@PROCID to a common error logging stored procedure. So there are some uses for this. But none natively in SQL

Comment: I need it for logging porpouses. Actually, int_proc is a trigger which logs any change on a particular field of a table. And since there are several procedure which update the table, I'd like to tell which one was invoked.